# Sending Parameters in a method using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, post, parameters, submit

How to send a parameter for the Form Submit Method??

This is what i'm trying.

```
 form.submit().val('#result').val(); // this doesnt work
```

I want to send the values of `$('#result')` to the form submit method. I,e. when I click on submit button in the form the `$(#result).val()` has a array of elements, which must be sent as a parameter to the submit method. `#result` is a paragraph. It is a POST method

```
  <form method="post" action="{{url('api/v1/vendors/store')}}">

                    <u><h1> New Vendor</h1></u>

      <div class="form-group row" id="myform">


            {{--  insertion for addresss table  --}}
            <label for="lgFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Bank A/C Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="A/c Number" name="bank_account_no">
              </div>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Bank Account Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Bank Account Name" name="bank_account_name">
              </div>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Account Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="A/c Type eg: sa, ca" name="account_type">
            </div>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Short code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Eg: INF, KFC" name="code">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Active</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            Activate <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" checked> <br>

              {{--  <input type="number"  class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Activation Status 0 or 1" name="active" >  --}}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">verified</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            Verified <input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="1" checked> <br>
              {{--  <input type="number"  class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Verification Status 0 or 1" name="verified" >  --}}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">verified_date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Date" name="verified_date">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">address_id</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Address ID fk" name="address_id">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">PAN Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="PAN Number" name="pancard_no">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Phone" name="phone_no">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Contact Person</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Contact Name" name="contact_person">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="smFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Contact Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="email" name="contact_email">
            </div>
          </div>

        {{--  submit button   --}}
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>


    </form>
</div>



<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $.fn.serializeObject = function()
  {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
  };

  $(function() {
      $('form').submit(function() {
          $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));

        //  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
         form.submit().val('#result');
          //return false;
      });
  });

  });


</script>

<h2>JSON</h2>
<pre id="result">
</pre>
```

Comment: Are you submit the form via ajax or form action?

Comment: submitting using form action, and the #result value contains a array of json.

Comment: Pls share your html code

Comment: If #result is paragraph element get the value using ('#result').text() method

Comment: just want to know how to send the values of  #result  when i click on submit. Thanks :D

Comment: Where is the id of result in your html???

Comment: sorry. I updated it just now                                                     
 `<h2>JSON</h2>
<pre id="result">
</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot easier if you use ajax,

Adjusting your code, Instead of sending a parameter you can pass the whole element with values coming from your `<pre>` tag Inside your form submit,
and also create a function that will run when your submit button is clicked.

--html--

- Add an id on your form

> ```
> <form id="yourForm">
> </form>
> ```

- Add an id for your Submit Button

> ```
> <div class="form-group row">
>       <div class="col-md-2"></div>
>       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitBtn">
> </div>
> ```

--javascript--

```
$(document).on("click","#SubmitBtn", function(){
   var pre_code = $("#result").html();
   $('#yourForm').append("<textarea name='myparam'>"+pre_code+"</textarea>");
   $('#yourForm').submit();

});
```

--api/v1/vendors/store file--

then you can access your param

```
$result = $_POST['myparam'];
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate. This would work perfect if i was using raw php, but i'm using laravel, You can't send anything but json api data. If you notice iv'e converted the form data into Json. Just need to pass em. using submit to send the array. {{url('api/v1/vendors/store')}}" > here /store is a method.